# add new field in magento(1.9) customer registration without changing core files

Tags: magento-1.9.1.1

I am new in Magento development and customization I am trying to add a mobile field in new customers registration form I have followed this article but I am stuck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501020/magento-add-a-field-on-default-registration-form

So, Please guide me through the perfect way without changing core files.

Comment: What is the error? Add your code also

Comment: now i solved the coding issue but then validation not working

Comment: You can add validation for input tag with class attribute. For example, class="validate-digits" or class="validate-phoneStrict". Please show your input-tag from html source to understand problem

Comment: thank you again for reviewing  here is my input tag   <li>
    <label for="mobile" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Mobile') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box"> <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getMobile()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Mobile') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-phoneStrict validate-email" />
    </div> 
    </li>

Comment: `class="input-text required-entry validate-phoneStrict validate-email"`
replace to
`class="input-text required-entry validate-phoneStrict"`

You don't need validate-email if you need phone number validation

Comment: # THANK YOU  Neklo.com  now it is all working.....

Comment: Please mark my answer as best answer. Thank you

Comment: Again thank you for remind about yes to this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li>
    <label for="mobile" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Mobile') ?></label> 
    <div class="input-box"> 
        <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getMobile()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Mobile') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-phoneStrict validate-email" /> 
    </div> 
</li>
```

replace to

```
<li>
    <label for="mobile" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Mobile') ?></label> 
    <div class="input-box"> 
        <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getMobile()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Mobile') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-phoneStrict" /> 
    </div> 
</li>
```

You don't need validate-email if you need phone number validation